# how to add wp_editor to textarea?

Tags: php, wordpress

there is a textbox which is output like this

```
<textarea id="myform" name="myform">
<?php echo esc_textarea( $post->prop( 'form' ) ); ?>
</textarea>
```

how can i add wp_editor?

i try

```
<textarea id="form" name="form" >
<?php echo wp_editor('esc_textarea( $post->prop( 'form' ) )', 'editor-form', array('teeny' => 0, 'tinymce' => 1); ?>
</textarea>
```

but this not work correctly

Comment: wp_editor itself renders the editor. There is no need to enclose it inside textarea tags.

Answer (score 1):

I understood, `<textarea></textarea>` should be changed to:

```php
    <?php
    $content = esc_textarea( $post->prop('form'));
    $editor_id = 'form';
    $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'form' );
    echo wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings); 
    ?>
```

All thanks for help.